# Spring reactive mongodb get subdocument

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux

My application has users and servers, every user can have multiple servers. I would like to get a server by giving the user Id and the server name.
Example database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a168093abfc7d0da1eaf039"),
    "email" : "test@test.com",
    "name" : "asdf",
    "password" : "$2a$10$sC2WjxBdmsmN/x4GI7rgS.HBr4C.W8oxFJ7p/WMC24YcoARX8pNba",
    "is_admin" : false,
    "servers" : [
        {
            "_id" : BinData(3,"5xEk0HAIc7P+JevFrKP5lQ=="),
            "name" : "asdf",
            "host" : "asdf",
            "ssl" : true
        }
    ],
    "_class" : "com.stack.database.main.model.User"
}
```

The user id is unique and the server name is unique per user. I would like to get the `Server` model(The servers list, not an actual `@Document` but a sub document) by giving the user id(`5a168093abfc7d0da1eaf039`) and the server name(`asdf`). I would like to use the repositories for this, the `ReactiveCrudRepository` repository.

I know I can get a user with a certain certain server name by using this in the `UserRepository`:

```
Mono<User> findByServers_Name(String name);
```

But I want to get the server model based on the user id and server name. I was thinking about something like this:

```
Mono<Server> findByIdAndServers_Name(ObjectId id, String name);
```

Note that this also has to be in the user model because the `Server` has no repository because it is a sub document.

How can I can a server model based on user id and server name with reactive crud repositories?

Comment: How many Users with how many servers do you expect?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I wan't to get a server by a user id and a server name, so I wan't to get one server.

Comment: It was more of a general question. With regards to the 16MB size limit of BSON documents.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg If the project would be a little bit popular 100 users with 1 to 3 servers.

Comment: Wrong tool for the job, then. This could be easily done with an embedded database or etcd, if you really have to have failover capabilities.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I needed a database that worked with reactive spring... Cassandra is not good for writing and updating, so I chose mongodb.